# Trying to get a simple animation to reset to its starting position, then begin again.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, reset

Essentially, trying to get a basic slider bar to go across a page over time, then when it reaches the end, slide back, and begin again. I can get it to slide back, just not start over. Help much appreciated.

Here's a what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/tG7Gm/282/ as well as the code below.

The CSS:

```
.slider {
height:0;
width:16.6%;
z-index:31;
padding-top:1%;
background-color:#398235;
position:relative;
}

.base {
text-align:left;
height:0;
width:100%;
z-index:30;
padding-top:1%;
border-top:1px solid #398235;
background-color:#c9de96;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
 }
```

The HTML:

```
    <div class="base">
                <div class="slider"><br></div>
            </div>
```

The JavaScript :

```
var x = 0;

var resetSlide = function() {
$('.slider').animate({left:'-=83.3%'}, 1000)

if (x === 0) {
    intervalID();
  }
 }


var intervalID = setInterval(function () {

$('.slider').animate({left:'+=16.66%'}, 1000)

if (++x === 5) {
   window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    x = 0;
    resetSlide();     
 }
}, 3500);



$(intervalID());
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `intervalID` as a function but it's integer, I have updated your code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tG7Gm/290/)

```
var x = 0;

var resetSlide = function() {
    $('.slider').animate({left:'-=83.3%'}, 1000)

    if (x === 0) {

        go();
    }
}

function go(){
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {

   $('.slider').animate({left:'+=16.66%'}, 1000)

   if (++x === 5) {
       window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        x = 0;
        resetSlide();     
   }
}, 35000);

}
go();
```

Comment: please post your code here as well cause links may change after time.

Comment: Great, that's almost exactly what I'm looking for. 

What would you recommend for getting the slider to wait 3.5 seconds (the amount of time it transitions for the other animation) before going back to the beginning?